# Jupyter Notebok - ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, localhost, timeout, jupyter

I've been facing this issue where the Jupyter notebook terminal closes thereby shutting down all python kernels I'd be working with at that time. The terminal shows this error message:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Exception in callback BaseSelectorEventLoop._read_from_self()
handle: <Handle BaseSelectorEventLoop._read_from_self()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bnarapar\Anaconda3\envs\env8520gpu\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\bnarapar\Anaconda3\envs\env8520gpu\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 119, in _read_from_self
    data = self._ssock.recv(4096)
```

I've seen some threads that say this is the host closing the connection because of a network change. While Jupyter runs on a local server and I'm not sure how a network change affects local server connections, I'm pretty sure I disabled any power management features on the network adapter.
Any help would be appreciated.

Jupyter versions:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0
jupyter_console           6.2.0                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.7.0            py37haa95532_0
jupyterlab                2.2.6                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the two sides of the connection trying to reuse the connection just as the server is closing it because it has been idle for too long.

Restarting the computer will solve the problem usually.